# How do I prevent text from moving when a Div is resized

Tags: html, css

I have been searching for the answer to this question for a while now but here is my issue.

I am trying to create a div that hugs the left side of the browser window and when it is hovered over, it will expand and hold more divs/text.

My question is, how do I make it so when the expanding div covers text, it does not move it, also how to make it so the text within the expanding div shrinks/grows with the div.

I have tried

```
position: relative
position: absolute
```

and all

```
text-align
```

possibilities

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97dLnb8a/1/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (Sorry if this question has been posted/answered in the past)

Comment: Imaginary CSS properties rock. There are no such things as `float: relative` or `absolute`.

Comment: Absolute and relative aren't valid values for the float property. Left, right, and none are.

Comment: Oh, dang I meant to put position:absolute/relative. My bad, thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqm9ksv8/

## Moving text below

Try absolute positioning for your `.grow`:

```
position: absolute;
```

That way, it'll not get into the way of other elements, instead be drawn on top of them.

## Shrinking text inside

To keep the text inside from shrinking, add another `div` inside, which has already the desired, fixed width. Add `overflow: hidden;` to the `.grow` container. That way, the contents will be layouted, but what does not fit the container is not being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use min-width to prevent div from resizing.

```
.Site-Content-Container{min-width: 960px;}
```

Edited: or maybe not. `position: absolute;` is an option. To be honest, it is not clear which text is not meant to resize.

Answer (score 0):

change your "float:left;" in .grow to "position:absolute;"

is that what you are aiming for?